# Increase in internal energy and temperature of a thermodynamics system

Tags: thermodynamics, conventions, thermal-conductivity

A banquet hall ($150 m^3$) is to be used for a formal dinner for 20 persons. Each person occupies $0.075 m^3$ of space and has an average heat transfer rate of $500 \frac{kJ}{hr}$. If the AC system fails, determine the increase in the internal energy and temperature of the air in the hall during the first 15 minutes of failure. Take the hall to be well insulated from outside. If the hall and all its contents are considered as system how much will be the increase in the internal energy of the system.

I am trying to use $Q= U + W$, don't have an idea about the data related to each person, why it is given. Thanks, please help.

Comment: What is your assessment so far?

Comment: If the room is initially at 20 C, and the pressure is 1 bar, how many moles of air are there in the room?

Comment: @ chet miller sir, trying to use q=u +w, taking 500kj/hr X 15 as heat supplied, don't have idea about person data, I think work done should be zero here

Comment: Correct and correct.  So how much heat do the people add to the air during the 15 minutes.  And how many moles of air are there in the room?

Comment: Mole of air was not given in the question sir

Comment: like I said, if the room is at 20 C and the pressure is 1 bar, what does the ideal gas law tell you is the number of moles of air in the room?

Comment: Then free volume will be used here for calculating the mole, by removing volume occupied by persons, thanks a lot sir,got it

Comment: But sir I doubt on using q=u +w, because it's true only for a process, overall it's just sum of heat transfer= sum of work and here no pressure and temperature are given to find mole, please help sir, thanks

Comment: @Chet Miller I wonder if we can assume that the number of moles of air will be constant? (or gas, since it’s composition will change due to breathing). Do humans exhale the same volume of gas as they inhale? I don’t know

Comment: Why is heating air in a room not a process?

Comment: @BobD At the OPs level, those things are neglected (and, on a time scale of 15 min, probably negligible anyway).

Answer (score 3):

If the walls are rigid then the system is isolated the total change in internal energy of the system (humans +room air) would be zero.

But when we consider the air in the room as the system the humans are then the surroundings. Any work done by or on the air in the room is due to the expansion and contraction of the human chests during breathing and would cancel out for a net work of zero on the room air. Therefore for the air in the room $\Delta U=Q$ where $Q$ is the heat transfer from the humans to the air in the room.

If we can assume the humans inhale and exhale the same volume of gas then the number of moles of gas is in the room is constant and can be calculated based on the initial condition information given (T,P,V) and ideal gas law. Finally, $\Delta U=nc_{v}\Delta T$ for an ideal gas, which we can assume for the air even though its composition is changing slightly (increase in carbon dioxide and decrease in oxygen).

Hope this helps